# Display image next to field value in kendo MVVM

Tags: html, mvvm, kendo-ui

Its been quite some time that I am stuck on this. What I want is to display an image next to each customer in the `CustomerName` field.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="example">

    <div data-role="grid"
         data-editable="true"
         data-columns="[
                         { 'field': 'CustomerID', 'width': 300},
                         { 'field': 'CustomerAltID', 'width': 300 },
                         { 'field': 'CustomerName', 'width': 500 },
                         { 'field': 'Gender', 'width': 200 }
                        ]"
         data-bind="source: productsSource"
         style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                productsSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: 'http://localhost:52738/Default1/KendoDataAjaxHandle',
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "Data",
                        total: function (response) {
                            return $(response.Data).length;
                        }
                    }
                })


            });

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

Now I am able to display the details with this much code but not getting to display an image.

What I want:

[image]

What i am getting:

[image]

So I tried doing something like this in data-column but I dont think its the right way:

```
data-columns="[
                         { 'field': 'CustomerID', 'width': 300,template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                                                            "style='background-image: url(../Content/Images/customerimg/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                                                        "<div class='customer-name'>#: CustomerName #</div>"},
```

I tried searching it on net and came across some template things but couldn't write something which would achieve my functionality.

I would be happy and thankful enough if someone would help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your templating approach is just fine but the resulting html is not. Using 'style:background-image' puts that image as the background of the element's content, but your div doesn't have any content which is why you see nothing. I believe you need something like an img tag for your picture followed by the customer name. Using a span instead of a div for the name should put the picture and text side by side. Try adjusting your template to render something along the lines of:

```
<img src='../Content/Images/customerimg/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg'></img>
<span>#: CustomerName #</span>
```